# How to fit size of the windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows project in that form size is varing fields are going beyound the screen so pls tell me how to set the form size for all screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindowState` property to `FormWindowState.Maximized`

Set the form property to open in maximized state. I hope it would help.

Comment: in that form i am adding image that is not showing properly

Comment: have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx @user3445262

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Width` and `Height` property of your form. Try like this:

```
this.Width = 200
this.Height = 300
```

Also, you can either set [Form.AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosizemode.aspx) property. Have a look at the example in the link too. Also, try to adjust [scrollbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.adjustformscrollbars.aspx) too.

Comment: in that form i am adding image that is not showing properly

Comment: Is the picturebox not showing image properly or the picturebox is going out of the form. Show us the screenshot. If you tried this you shouldn't have the problem.

Comment: picturebox is going out of the form.

Comment: Either try my solution or change the `Location` of your `PictureBox` to reside inside the form.

Comment: i have one more question can i ask u??

Comment: I have CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe software i want add it in my visual studio application.when i an installing my appllication need to install "CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe" this software pls provide the screen shots or steps

Comment: This is totally a different question, so you should open a new question and tag question with relevant zones, otherwise you and me will both suffer.

Comment: i posted but no one replying

Comment: actually i have picture box in that i have fields but that position cant change

Comment: I currently do not have .Net IDE when back, will check if possible to have something to share. For now, focus on here. Have you tried to set the properties i highlighted ?

Comment: ya wen i run normally it ll show but when i create setup and open the application thattime problem is occuring..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Comment: i should i put in form load ()